# Pixel offset with 100% width

Tags: css, width, percentage

I've done this in the past before, I believe using padding. The idea is that I want two elements (div's) side-by-side (floats) where has a percentage (100%) width and the other has a fixed pixel with (50px).

Poorly draw illustration:

```
------------------------------------------------
|              100%             |     50px     |
------------------------------------------------
```

I don't want any of the following

- javascript
- less then 100% width like 95% etc wont work

Comment: So do you want 50px off the side of the window; or have the 50px on the right and everything to the left is the other div?

Comment: that was an either or question... did you want the first method or the second?

Comment: Oh sorry @DevonBernard I want to eventually shove this whole thing inside a container div. This was what I came up with http://jsfiddle.net/reggi/3vrYv/

Comment: Alright so what do you want changed. Do you want the yellow div area to fill the black div area?

Comment: @DevonBernard That is a working example fulfills my requirements, it uses some hack-stuff (absolute). Not sure if there is an alternative method out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JCV8L/)

```
#one
{
  width:100%;
  float:right;
}

#two
{
  width:50px;
  margin-right:-100%;
  float:right;
}
```

This is of course, after adding the clearfix solution to the parent div.

This is perhaps not the most semantic way of doing things but it works. If you use this method, I suggest you you add another div in the first div(which has the 100% width) for your content.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from your fiddle you may have solved it the way I thought might be the only way possible, with absolute positioning and then padding to give it room to breathe in. You know you can post your own answer to your question :D

Here's your working answer code for others that may have the same problem and want the answer directly, without a fiddle:

HTML

```
<div class="black">
    <div class="yellow">
    </div>
    <div class="purple">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.black{background:black;padding-right:70px;height:100px;position:relative;}
.yellow{background:yellow;width:100%;height:100%;}
.purple{background:purple;width:50px;height:100%;margin:0 0 0 20px;position:absolute;right:0;top:0;}
```

Comment: But what if he wanted to put that div anywhere else on the page other than the very top... The absolute makes that purple tag always load in the top right; he only did that to show us what he wanted it to look like... I am assuming he wants the freedom to put that div where-ever he wants.

Comment: He said that his code from his fiddle accomplishes what he wants in the comments. And your comment is not accurate, the absolute positioned elements are contained in a relative positioned element so "0 0" for the absolutely positioned elements is the top left of the div.black element.

Comment: Maybe so, I thought he just wanted the two divs without the container div to display what he wanted; but whatever works, works. I just thought he must have wanted some adjustment; other-wise why post the question?

Comment: He posted the question and then solved it himself. As to why he posted the comment, I believe he was unaware you can post an answer to your own question.